# python logging: is it possible to add module name to formatter

Tags: python

It is possible to get a logger by module name. Like this:

```
logging.getLogger(module_name)
```

I would like to add `module_name` to every log record. Is it possible to set up a `Formatter` object which adds `module_name`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for the `%(name)s` parameter; add that to your formatter pattern:

```
FORMAT = "%(name)s: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
```

or when creating a `Formatter()`:

```
FORMAT = "%(name)s: %(message)s"
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=FORMAT)
```

See the [`LogRecord` attributes reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):

> *Attribute name*: `name`
>   *Format*: `%(name)s`
>   *Description*: Name of the logger used to log the call.

Answer (score 4):

when you initialize the logger (only need to do this once for the app) try this config

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='var/bpextract.log',
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s  %(process)-7s %(module)-20s %(message)s',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
    )
```

...later in your code...

```
log = logging.getLogger("bpextract")
log.info('###### Starting BPExtract App #####')
```

Comment: This doesn't include the name `bpextract` in the log messages; you are including the module *where the call came from* to the log messages. If you used the `log` object in a different module the entry would also differ.

Comment: The name passed into the `getLogger()` call is avairable as `%(name)s` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In `logging.basicConfig`, you can specify the format:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(name)s\t%(message)s')
```